# Xamarin forms ListView Capture Double tap and Context actions

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an interesting problem I wanted to add a double tap event to my list view  the only way i made it work was that i added a gesture to my data templates viewcell stacklayout

```
                     <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding 
                         BindingContext.GetItemDetailCommand,  Source=
                         {x:Reference Name=page}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                          NumberOfTapsRequired="2"/>
                      </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
```

then I lost the context actions

```
                 <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                    <MenuItem Text="Delete"  Command="{Binding BindingContext.DeleteCommand,  Source={x:Reference Name=page}}"      
                             CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
```

so i added to my stack panel `InputTransparent="True"` so the event should bubble up then the context action started working again but i lost the double tap : (